# Compact consecutive numbers with positionList

Tags: java

I only get this error but I still do not know why

> compactar({2,2,2,2})>>>> {2}
>
> compactar({2,2,null,null,2,3})>>>>{2,null,2,3}
>
> compactar({2,2,1,2})>>>>{2,1,2}
>
> compactar({})>>>>{}
>
> compactar({1,2,3,null,null})>>>>{1,2,3,null}
>
> compactar({null})>>>>{null}
>
> compactar(null)>>>>IllegalArgumentException

I have made several changes but I really can not find the result. The method basically seeks to compact the consecutive elements equal to a single appearance.

```
public <E> PositionList<E> compactar (PositionList<E> lista) {
PositionList<E> list= new NodePositionList<E>();
Position<E> cursor=list.first();


if(lista==null ) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}// de if

Position <E> cursor1= list.last();
while(cursor!=null) {
        if(cursor.equals(lista.next(cursor))) {
            Position<E> borrar=cursor;
            cursor=lista.next(cursor);
            lista.remove(borrar);
            list.addLast(cursor.element());
        }// de if 
}// de bucle for 
return list;
}// de compactar
```

Comment: *I only get this error but I still do not know why*: what do you think `if(lista==null ) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}` does? Did you actually write this code, or did you copy and paste it without understanding it?

Comment: Because If the "lista" parameter is null, an exception is thrown

Comment: You're asking why you get an IllegalArgumentException when you pass null to your method. Your method checks if the argument and throws an IllegalArgumentException if the argument is null. So isn't the answer quite obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Your third line should be `...lista.first()` (not list) and it should be *after* you checked that `lista` isn’t null

Comment: ok, but idea to compare consecutive numbers taking the exception in null?